# How to setup different CodeSniffer executables for different projects?

Tags: phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

I have a problem, that some of my projects loaded into PhpStorm IDE requires different CodeSniffer versions because of different Code Style conventions.

If I go to `Settings -> PHP -> Code Sniffer`, I can choose only global CS executable.

[image]

Is there a way to have different CodeSniffer executables for different projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it is not possible at the moment. The support suggested to keep two installations of PhpStorm with different settings.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/project-and-ide-settings.html